# CMake: Install an export file in Debug/Release alternatively?

Tags: cmake

Take the following example as a start:

```
...
add_library(Foo ...)
install(TARGETS Foo EXPORT FooTargets
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
...
)

install(EXPORT FooTargets
 FILE lib/cmake/Foo
...
)
```

Running this with

```
$ mkdir build; cd build
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .. (or in Debug)
$ cmake --build .
$ cmake --install . --prefix my/custom/prefix
```

This will create the files:

```
my/custom/prefix/lib/cmake/Foo/FooTargets.cmake
my/custom/prefix/lib/cmake/Foo/FooTargets-release.cmake (Or debug, respectively)
my/custom/prefix/lib/libFoo.a
```

And from what I managed to understand from the `FooTargets.cmake` file, it globs for all `FooTargets-*.cmake` files and `includes()` them all.

In turn, the `FooTargets-release.cmake` file is the one that references the `libFoo.a` file.

In the docs about the `install` command, it says that you can add the `CONFIGURATIONS` option to the `install TARGETS` command, so that if we change the above:

```
install(TARGETS Foo EXPORT FooTargets
   CONFIGURATIONS Debug
   LIBRARY DESTINATION lib/Debug
   ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib/Debug
```

This will install the `libFoo.a` file in `my/custom/path/lib/Debug/libFoo.a`. Now let's say I want the Release library to be installed in `lib/Release` and the Debug library be installed in `lib/Debug`, and that when the downstream project will consume my package, it will have the right library depending on its configuration - i.e. - debug build will link against the Debug library, same for release.

What I thought I can do is:

```
install(TARGETS Foo EXPORT FooTargets
   CONFIGURATIONS Debug
   LIBRARY DESTINATION lib/Debug
   ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib/Debug
)

install(TARGETS Foo EXPORT FooTargets 
  CONFIGURATIONS Release
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib/Release
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib/Release
)

install(EXPORT FooTargets 
  DESTINATION lib/cmake/Foo
  ...
)
```

And what will happen is that when building in `Debug`, the `FooTargets-debug.cmake` will be generated, pointing to the `lib/Debug/libFoo.a`, and when building in Release, the `FooTargets-release.cmake` will be generated, pointing to the `lib/Release/libFoo.a`. The `FooTargets.cmake` will then check what configuration is the consuming project is building with, and include the right configuration.

When I try doing the above, I get:

```
-- Configuring done
CMake Error: install(EXPORT "FooTargets" ...) includes target "Foo" more than once in the export set.
-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

How is this should be done??

### EDIT

I found out, in a not-very-straightforward way, that when I build the consuming project as such:

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
```

and like this:

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
```

I am linking against only the relevant library. Basically how this works is that the `FooTargets.cmake` file is included by the `FooConfig.cmake` file, which is called by `find_package`. The `FooTargets.cmake` file is the one that defines the imported target:

```
add_library(Foo IMPORTED)
```

This file then calls all the `FooTargets-*.cmake`, which adds the relevant library to some list called `_IMPORT_CHECK_FILES_FOR_FOO`.
What this file also does, is:

```
set_property(TARGET Foo::Foo APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS RELEASE)
```

Apparently there is some property IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS that holds the imported configurations.

I suppose that somewhere down the road, `find_package` takes this list and filters it according to the CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE variable, and this way links only the relevant library.

What I still don't understand, is how to make it so that upon Release builds (of Foo), the `FooTargets-release.cmake` will be created, pointing to `lib/Release/Foo.a`, and the same for debug builds.

It seems that CMake went half-way with this, unless I'm seriously missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems per-CONFIGURATIONS installs are not easily fit to EXPORT semantic.

However, in simple cases per-configuration's specific can be achieved by using [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) in DESTINATION:

```
install(TARGETS Foo EXPORT FooTargets
   LIBRARY DESTINATION lib/$<CONFIG>
   ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib/$<CONFIG>
)

install(EXPORT FooTargets 
  DESTINATION lib/cmake/Foo
  ...
)
```

The code above will install libraries into `lib/Debug` for Debug configuration, and into `lib/Release` for Release configuration.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev, why is generator expression better here than `${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}`?

Comment: `${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}` doesn't work in case of multiconfiguration generators (like Visual Studio), but generator expressions works.